# ¿Como editar Selects anidados jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, post, select2

Hola tengo este problema con dos select2 anidados (uno depende del otro), lo primero es que lleno un datatable.net con los datos y de estos los paso mediante oneclick para poder editarlos:

```
EditarTrabajador = function ( CodOficina, DepOficina) {

 $.post("/Oficina/OficinaGeneral",
     function (data) {
         $.each(data, function (i, item) {
             $('#Ecbooficinageneral').append('<option value="' + item.Cod_Oficina_G + '">' + item.Nom_OFicina_G + '</option>');
             $("#Ecbooficinageneral").val(DepOficina);
             $('#Ecbooficinageneral').change();             
         });
     });

 $('#Ecbooficinageneral').on('change', function () {        
            var codofi = $('#Ecbooficinageneral').val();            
                $('#Ecbooficinadep').val(null).trigger('change');
                $('#Ecbooficinadep').html('<select class="form-control select2" id="cbooficinadep" style="width: 100%;">' +
                                        '<option selected="selected" value="">Seleccione Oficina Dependiente</option>' +
                                        '</select>');
                $.post("/Oficina/OficinaDep",
                    { codoficina: codofi },
                    function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            $('#Ecbooficinadep').append('<option value="' + item.Cod_Oficina_D + '">' + item.Nom_Oficina_D + '</option');
                            $("#Ecbooficinadep").val(CodOficina);
                            $('#Ecbooficinadep').change();
                        });
                    });
        });

}
```

el problema es que al momento de llenar el primer combo y poner:

```
$("#Ecbooficinageneral").val(DepOficina);
$('#Ecbooficinageneral').change();
```

el change hace que se llene el mismo dato en el siguiente combo varias veces, como puedo hacer que es cargue el primer select con la opcion a editar, limpiar el segundo select y cargarla con la opcion a editar igualmente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, ¿Por que razón tienes el evento declarado dentro de la función?.

Podrías ponerlo en el contexto global del js o en el load de la pagina.
Haciéndolo de esta forma lo estas asociando una vez iniciada la función.

Según la documentación de `Select2`

> change:   Triggered whenever an option is selected or removed.
>
> change: se dispara cada vez que se selecciona o elimina una opción.

Te recomiendo usar este.

> select2:select    Triggered whenever a result is selected.
>
> select2:select Disparo cuando se selecciona un resultado.

El uso es simple

```
$('#mySelect2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var data = e.params.data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Ademas tienes acceso a los datos seleccionados realmente.

```
e.params.data = 
{
  "id": 1,
  "text": "Tyto alba",
  "genus": "Tyto",
  "species": "alba"
}
```

Mas sobre Select2 https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

Answer (score 0):

Estas funciones llenan cualquier tipo de combo:

```
 function llenarCmb(combo, datos) {
        combo.find('option').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != "-1") {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
            combo.append("<option value='" + datos[i]["id"] + "'>" + datos[i]["nombre"] + "</option>");
        }
    }
    function llenarCombo(name, rutaControlador, strAccion, funcAppendCombo, id_cmb_padre) {
        $("select[name=" + name + "]").each(function () {
            combo = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: rutaControlador,
                data: { accion: strAccion, id_padre: id_cmb_padre },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (datos) {
                    funcAppendCombo(combo, datos);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //console.log(jqXHR);
                    alert("No se pudo cargar el combo " + name + " : " + textStatus + ' Thrown: ' + errorThrown);
                },
                complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                    //console.log(jqXHR);
                    //alert("complete\njqXHR="+jqXHR+"\nstatus="+status);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Y estos son ejemplos de como llamarla:

```
llenarCombo("nameComboIndependiente", "url", "metodoAejecutarEnElServer", llenarCmb, null);//Combo independiente           
$("#idComboIndependiente").change(function () {
     llenarCombo("nameComboDependiente", "url", "OtroMetodoAejecutarEnElServer", llenarCmb, $(this).val());//Combo dependiente
});
```

Las funciones siempre esperan un json de `[{id:valorId,nombre:valorNombre},{id:valorId,nombre:valorNombre}]` que tienes que armar en el lenguaje del server java,php,c# y en ningun momento violas el MVC.